Nuget requesting irrelevant packages
In Visual Studio 2022, NuGet is reporting a NU1301 error for a package (packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.7.2) that's irrelevant to the current VS solution. How do I clear this error?

Error (active)    NU1301  Failed to retrieve information about
'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref' from remote source
'https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.7.2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.

Moreover, this NU1301 error is saying this package reference is occurring in Line 1 of the VS *.csproj file. But the *.csproj file makes no such reference to this package in the first place. So what's going on? What's confusing Visual Studio and NuGet?
(I do use this package in a totally different VS solution, however, for a separate application.)

Apparently there's a third party library that my project solution is using that requires the System.Drawing.Common 4.7.2 assembly (which I didn't know about). That third party library was installed by another application, which placed that assembly in its install directory.
When my own solution code called that third party library, Visual Studio griped that the System.Drawing.Common 4.7.2 assembly was not installed for my solution--and apparently it needs to be.
So getting the VS NuGet packet manager to install the System.Drawing.Common 4.7.2 assembly in my solution fixed the problem.
I would like to thank those that pointed me to the NuGet packet manager for solving this illusive problem.

Glad to hear that this issue doesn't block you anymore. Happy Coding

From looking at NuGet Error NU1301, it looks like  the listed source is unavailable.
Is the following source configured as your package source in the Nuget.conifg file ?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.7.2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref'&semVerLevel=2.0.0

Note: Nuget config file is located to  %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config (Windows)
Here are suggestions you can check to troubleshoot the issue:
1.Add a NuGet.config in solution folder and Manually Add Package Source.
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

2.Clear NuGet Cache
 nuget locals all -clear

3 This issue is similar to Failed to retrieve information from remote source, please check if it helps.
